# Unable to filter by calculated datetime when pulling data from MySQL into MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, servicenow

I'm connecting from MS SQL Server 2014 to a (ServiceNow) MySQL database via OpenQuery(). I would like to filter out records more than 24 hours old. 
When I set a static date, it returns the thousands of rows I expect to see. However, when I try to use a calculated field, it runs but returns zero records.

```sql
select number, sys_updated_on 
from OPENQUERY(ServiceNowUAT, 
'Select number, sys_updated_on
FROM DATABASE.[SCHEMA].[TableName]
WHERE sys_updated_on  > DATEADD(d, -2, NOW()) ')
```

I have also used the `DATE_SUB()` function, and various other forms of syntax. I've tried casting the calculated date as date, datetime, timestamp, varchar, and more. I've tried this in MS Query and SSIS as well. All fail to return results with this query, and other, similar queries once I add the "`sys_updated_on  > DATEADD(d, -2, NOW())`" segment.

If I cast the sys_update_on field as timestamp, it works, but cranks up the processing time from about 10 seconds to 30+ minutes, which, of course, is not ideal (there are a few million rows in the table

The `sys_update_on` field is in the format "`2015-02-10 10:24:17.000000`".

The other relevant part is that I am pulling from a ServiceNow MySQL database using ODBC drivers provided by ServiceNow, not MySQL. I do not have a data map, so I cannot say for sure what the data type is. At this point, I'm guessing it's a string of some sort, and not a true timestamp/datetime, but I can't confirm this.

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work so that it
a. returns results
b. does not take half an hour to run?

Comment: What is the current data type of `sys_updated_on`? Is it being stored as a string? Have you considered using the right data type for the column?

Comment: sounds like string comparison is failing.  What happens when you force NOW() to be the same string format with something like:`DATEADD(d, -2, NOW())` to `DATE_FORMAT(DATEADD(d, -2, NOW()),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')`

Comment: Also, I don't think DATEADD is a MySql function, so I'm surprised it's getting through OpenQuery() without an error.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Ben. Unfortunately, I get an error "Unsupported scalar function:DATE_FORMAT"  It does allow DATE_SUB, but doesn't seem to allow the normal DATE_SUB format of DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY). Maybe this is a problem of a limit to which MySQL functions work in OpenQuery?

Comment: Thank you, Aaron. The data type of sys_updated_on is timestamp in the mysql database.

Comment: I've had to do this as dynamic SQL in the past.  It's be nice if openquery worked as openquery(datasource,@ query), but it won't accept the variable there.   set @ sql = 'select number...WHERE sys_updated_on  >'' ' + DATEADD(d, -2, NOW())+''' (you might have to convert this dateadd function to a char to add it to the @ sql variable).  Then  exec @ sql.

Comment: Hi Twelfth, that works within SSMS! Thank you for that!  The code I ended up using was:

Comment: Hi Twelfth, that works within SSMS! Thank you for that!  Now I have to figure out if I can use this in SSIS, or whether I want to move the rest of my code from SSIS to stored procedures.  The code I ended up using was:  'DECLARE @ TSQL varchar(8000) 
'DECLARE @ VAR varchar(29) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(d, '-2, getdate()), 120)
'SET @ TSQL = 

'select number, sys_updated_on from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
''Select number, sys_updated_on
FROM database.sxhema.table
WHERE 
sys_updated_on  > ''''' + @VAR  + ''''''')
ORDER BY 2 asc
'

EXEC (@ TSQL)

Comment: So, the other solution that worked was casting the sys_updated_on field as datetime, and also adding an addition date limitation on the un-casted sys_updated_on field (WHERE sys_Updated_on < '2014-10-01'. The problem is that this is not sustainable, as the performance will begin to suffer after a few months/years if I don't go back in and change the static date.  I would like to make a simple modification so that I don't have to rewrite the entire SSIS package.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the ServiceNow ODBC driver to connect the linked server, which means you're not actually connecting to the MySQL database. The ODBC driver is really just a facade around a SOAP interface that translates "SQL" into SOAP requests. This would explain why you're able to execute sql which wouldn't be valid on Mysql, and can add a layer of frustrating complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
 FROM OpenQuery(ServiceNowUAT, 
     'SELECT name FROM DATABASE.[SCHEMA].[TableName]
      WHERE CAST(sys_updated_on as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, now()) and now()'
)
```

[Spark Interactive SQL Reference.pdf](https://community.servicenow.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/651260-5846/Spark%20Interactive%20SQL%20Reference.pdf)